# Change my terminal from x-term to mate-terminal when I click open terminal here

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

How can I change my terminal from x-term to mate-terminal so when I click open terminal here it uses mate-terminal?

I use Thunar as my file manager.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator
```

Then when it gives you options, choose your desired one:

```
  1            /usr/bin/lxterm                   30        manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/terminator               50        manual mode
  3            /usr/bin/uxterm                   20        manual mode
* 4            /usr/bin/xfce4-terminal.wrapper   40        manual mode
  5            /usr/bin/xterm                    20        manual mode
```

Comment: I picked /usr/bin/mate-terminal.wrapper. It works but gives this message when I close the terminal. Failed to execute default Terminal Emulator. input/output error. @Ravexina

Comment: @fixit7 I'm not sure what could be the cause of problem, you can ask another question about it, maybe someone else knows how to fix it ...

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. As Thunar is my file manager, I made this custom action.

```
Open terminal here

mate-terminal --working-directory=%f
```